# Lattice iCE40-HX8K Board - UART

Tags: verilog, fpga, uart

I have the following verilog code for my Lattice iCE40-HX8K Board:

uart.v:

```
module uart(input clk, output TXD);

reg [3:0] count;
reg [9:0] data;
reg z;

initial begin

data[9:0] = 10'b1000000000; // Startbit = 1, Stopbit = 0

z = 0;

end

always@(posedge clk)
begin

  if(count == 1250) //9600x per Second (1250) = Baudrate
    begin

      count <= 0;

      TXD = data[z];

      z = z + 1;
 if(z == 10)
        begin
        z = 0;
        end
      else
        begin
        end

    end
  else
    begin
      count <= count + 1;
    end


end

endmodule
```

For receiving the UART-Data I use gtkterm under Ubuntu 14.04.
I have set the baudrate in gtkterm to 9600.
If I now program my FPGA with the code I receive once per programming a 
hex "00" (irrespective of the 8 usage-bits).

[image]

Can anybody give me a hint what is wrong?

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two obvious problems with your design:

1. Your `count` is only 4 bits wide, thus it cannot count to 1250. It must be at least 11 bits wide to be able to count to 1250.
2. Also your `z` is only 1 bit wide, so it can only hold the values 0 and 1. It must be at least 4 bits wide to be able to count to 10.

You should also read up on [blocking vs. non-blocking assignments](http://www.ece.cmu.edu/~ece447/s13/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=synth-verilog-cummins.pdf). The way you use blocking assignments in sequential logic can lead to race conditions in the verilog simulation model.

You should *always* write testbenches for your HDL code and simulate it *before* trying to run it in hardware. A testbench for your design would be as easy as:

```
module uart_testbench;
        reg clk = 1;
        always #5 clk = ~clk;

        uart uut (
                .clk(clk)
        );

        initial begin
                $dumpfile("uart.vcd");
                $dumpvars(0, uut);
                repeat (1000000) @(posedge clk);
                $finish;
        end
endmodule
```

Comment: First, thank you for your fast response. I've fixed the issues you've mentioned and now I am receiving an endless chain of "J" (Image: [link]https://embdev.net/attachment/267072/Screenshot_from_2015-09-05_16_32_19.png[/link]).
But if I take a look at the data bits inside "data" (I've changed it to data[9:0] = 10'b0010100101; // Startbit = 0, Stopbit = 1):

01010010

I should receive a ASCII "R".
My question is now why I am getting a "J" instead of an "R"?
Thank you a lot :)

Comment: @user5228734 at least occasionally you should add a pause (longer than a symbol) between stop and start bit so the receiver has a chance to synchronize to the symbol boundary. Otherwise it will interpret some of your data bits as start/stop bits and your start/stop bits as part of the payload. Especially if repeat the same 10-bit pattern over and over again: how should the receiver know where the byte boundaries are without a pause between two symbols to synchronize on?